# jQuery datatables - Index Column print/download issue

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using a jquery datatables api [index column](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html). I've managed to make the table work by following the documentation shown on the page. 
I also used the Buttons plugin to print the table, but in the "index" -- or in my case I named it "Bil" -- column, the numbers are not printed out. 
The same problem occurs when I want to view the data after downloading the table in Excel and PDF.

The output when I wanted to print the table: 
[image: example table]

I don't know if it is a bug or not since I can't find the issue raised else where. I suspect the index value was only loaded to the page but is not inserted into the table. Is there a workaround to maybe use javascript to insert the value inside the table's  ?

Here is the datatable's javascript that is responsible for the indexing:

```
//Datatable
var t = $('#tablePelajarLama').DataTable({
     dom: 'lBfrtip',
     buttons: [
         'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
     ],
   "columnDefs": [ {
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 0
   } ],
   "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
 });

//index counter
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
  t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
       cell.innerHTML = i+1;
  } );
} ).draw();
```

On a side note, I use PHP to load the data into the table if it in any way affects the process. Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What exactly do you get and what is the desired output??

Comment: @LelioFaieta The issue is that when I wanted to print, the numbers disappears. The index numbers also disappears when I download the table. What I get in my webpage is just like the example I linked to. The desired output is to get the missing numbers visible when I want to print it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use [`cell().invalidate()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.invalidate%28%29) API method to tell DataTables to re-read the information from the DOM for the cell holding the index.

```
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
   t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
      cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
      t.cell(cell).invalidate('dom'); 
   } );
} ).draw();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsgeex1h/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. Unfortunately though, it makes my table impossible to load. Too many data to load since it works when I try it on a table with less data.

Comment: @wsssixteen, you may be right, I have tested the code on the small dataset. How many records do you have? And do you use Ajax sourced data or HTML sourced data?

Comment: I have thousands of records to load. I am using database datatable sourced data. I am still learning on how to load the data into ajax..

Comment: If I may ask here, will it really make enough difference in speed if I were to use AJAX method? Even if I have to load like thousands of data? Because my time is currently limited, and I want to know if it is worth learning for now because I have my hands full.

Comment: Yes - Ajax data will be much faster since at the moment there is a write and read to the DOM, while with Ajax there is only a write (change `dom` to `data` if you make the change). However, you'll only know how much of an improvement if you try it. Don't burn me if it isn't a big enough improvement! Oh, and turn on the `deferRender` option in DataTables if you use Ajax data!

Comment: @AllanJardine  I've decided to give it a try. Thanks for that info! I believe that would save me from the trouble to debug the code later on.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!